# How to remove Button in Datatable File upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am currently using Datatable in this link:
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/upload-many.html

At this code make you upload a image.

```
        {
            label: "Images:",
            name: "files[].id",
            type: "uploadMany",
            display: function ( fileId, counter ) {
                return '<img src="'+editor.file( 'files', fileId ).web_path+'"/>';
            },
            noFileText: 'No images'
        }
```

What I want is to remove X button.
Please check the link for code references

[image]

[image]

Comment: sharing a screen shot is not enough to solve your problem. you need to share the relevant html and jquery code with plugin details

Comment: use css & do display:none for that button.

Comment: I think that button is to remove the uploaded file. If file will not be there, that X button will not be there.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar sorry Sir I keep modify my question to easy to understand

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I think it is a default button of datatable, I don't know how to remove that default

Comment: @Saawant After Inspect the code there's no ID or Name in the button, because its default button for that data-table

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I have a role that user can Upload but they can't remove it after uploading. So I need to remove the X button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inspect element the button to get id/name/classname, in my case there's no ID or name so I try to use classname.

```
<style>
    .btn-default.remove{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```